# Java Swing - Center a JLabel using BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

I have an assignment, and the instructions specify that I need two labels to be centered on the screen (both horizontally and vertically). 
I know this question has been asked many times, but whenever I have searched for this question, the solution given is often to use a different layout manager, like BoxLayout. However, the instructions also specify that I must use BorderLayout.
Originally I did not add the labels to a panel and instead added them directly to the frame, but this didn't work, so I was advised to put them both on a JPanel, which hasn't worked either.

My code looks like this currently:

```
    JButton butSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
    JButton butReset = new JButton("Reset");

    JLabel nameAndReg = new JLabel("My details", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    JLabel errorMsg = new JLabel("The error message", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    nameAndReg.setForeground(Color.blue);

    JTextField redVal = new JTextField(3);
    JTextField greenVal = new JTextField(3);
    JTextField blueVal = new JTextField(3);

    JPanel butPanelSouth = new JPanel();
    JPanel butPanelNorth = new JPanel();
    JPanel labsPanel = new JPanel();

    butPanelSouth.add(redVal);
    butPanelSouth.add(greenVal);
    butPanelSouth.add(blueVal);
    butPanelSouth.add(butSubmit);
    butPanelNorth.add(butReset);
    labsPanel.add(nameAndReg, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    labsPanel.add(errorMsg, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    add(labsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(butPanelNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(butPanelSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

And this is what it produces:
[image: Current result]

How can I get 'My details' and 'The error message' to be vertically and horizontally in the middle of the window, one under the other, and still use BorderLayout?

Edit: Sorry, I realise I wasn't very clear. The advice I was given was 'perhaps nest your layout managers i.e. put a JPanel in the centre of a BorderLayout on  a JFrame.'

Comment: Are you assuming your JLabel isn't in the centre because of the text? You can change the backcolor of your JLabel and see where the entire JLabel is located first. It might already be in the centre if you already tried all approaches.

Comment: All your panels **must** use `BorderLayout` (it would be crazy ...), or you can use nested panels with different `LayoutManagers`? Now you are using `FlowLayout` for your sub panels (if you don't pass a layout to the `JPanel` constructor, `FlowLayout` is used )

Comment: Actually, now that I re-read what I was advised to do, it says 'perhaps nest your layout managers i.e. put a JPanel in the centre of a BorderLayout on a JFrame.'

Comment: @electricbl00 So, i think my answer should meet your requirements :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i said in the comment above, you should clarify what do you mean when you say "the instructions also specify that I must use `BorderLayout`".

If you mean that your content pane must have a `BorderLayout`, and the other panels can have a different layout (like in your code, since you are using a `FlowLayout` in your sub panels), it's easy to solve your issue.

You just need to add your labels in a `JPanel` which uses a layout that aligns the labels at the center, like `GridBagLayout` does.
Your first label will have `gridx = 0` and `gridy = 0`, the second label will have `gridx = 0` and `gridy = 1`.
Your second will be exactly below the first one, you can use `insets` to create some empty space (in the code below i use 5 pixels for `Insets.top`).

Since your `labsPanel` will be at `BorderLayout.CENTER`, the panel will take all the empty space in your frame, and `GridBagConstrains.anchor` default value (`GridBagConstrains.CENTER`) makes sure your labels are centered inside your `labsPanel`. As a result, the labels will be vertically and horizontally aligned at the middle of the frame, like in the screeenshot below:

[image]

Code sample:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Test
{
    public static void main (String [] a) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater (new Runnable () {
            @Override public void run () {
                createAndShowGUI ();
            }
        });
    }
    private static void createAndShowGUI () {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane (new MainPanel ());
        frame.pack ();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo (null);
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }
}
class MainPanel extends JPanel
{
    public MainPanel () {
        super (new BorderLayout ());

        JLabel nameAndReg = new JLabel ("My details", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        JLabel errorMsg = new JLabel ("The error message", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        nameAndReg.setForeground(Color.blue);

        JPanel labsPanel = new JPanel (new GridBagLayout ());

        labsPanel.add (nameAndReg);

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints ();
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets (5, 0, 0, 0);
        labsPanel.add (errorMsg, c);

        JButton butSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
        JButton butReset = new JButton("Reset");

        JTextField redVal = new JTextField(3);
        JTextField greenVal = new JTextField(3);
        JTextField blueVal = new JTextField(3);

        JPanel butPanelSouth = new JPanel ();
        JPanel butPanelNorth = new JPanel ();

        butPanelSouth.add (redVal);
        butPanelSouth.add (greenVal);
        butPanelSouth.add (blueVal);
        butPanelSouth.add (butSubmit);

        butPanelNorth.add (butReset);

        add (labsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add (butPanelNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add (butPanelSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

If **all** your panels must have a `BorderLayout`, it's very difficult to achieve what you want, but as i said, it would be a crazy requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The code posted simply has a bug. The following line:

```
labsPanel.add(nameAndReg, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

is inconsistent with the panel's construction - the no-arg constructor defaults to Flow Layout (hence why the 2 labels added appear next to each other):

```
JPanel labsPanel = new JPanel();
```

To use Border Layout constraints, the panel must use a `BorderLayout`:

```
JPanel labsPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
```

But note that you can only add a single component to the `CENTRE` location of a `BorderLayout`. You may need to nest yet another `JPanel` if you want those 2 labels to "flow" together, in the vertical centre.